# Need help solving the following finite summation

Tags: summation

$$\left(\frac12\right)^x\sum_{y=1}^x \left(\frac23\right)^y$$
I need help solving this finite summation step by step. Thank you

Comment: What have you tried, and where did you get stuck? The finite sum is that of a geometric progression. Do you know the sum of $\sum_{k=0}^n a^k\,$?

Comment: I do not know that sum. I have not computed a finite sum before.

Comment: Do you know the identity $a^n-1=(a-1)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\cdots+a+1)\,$?

Comment: I do not know that identity

Comment: Then, sorry, but tell whoever gave you this problem that you don't have the necessary background to solve it. Getting a random answer on MSE will not help you much next time you have to solve a similar problem.

Comment: I was looking for a step by step solution for it, which would help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is the formula for a finite geometric series. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) for the wikipedia article on the formula and its derivation. I repeat it here for emphasis:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n ar^{i-1} = \frac{a(1-r^{n+1})}{1-r} $$
Note that there are $n$ terms in the sum and that the first term is $a$. Try applying this formula to your problem. You may need to factor out some constants from your sum in order to get your problem into the same form as the formula above. Try to explicitly state what $a$, $n$, and $r$ are, and make sure your sum starts at 1, in order to use this formula.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Let the sum you seek be $S_x$. Simplify $S_x-(\frac23)S_x$.

Answer (score 0):

> I was looking for a step by step solution for it, which would help me.

- Prove, by induction or otherwise, the identity $a^n-1=(a-1)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}+\cdots+a+1)\,$
- Note that the above is equivalent (for $a\ne 1$) to $\;1+a+\cdots+ a^{n-2}+a^{n-1} = \cfrac{1-a^n}{1-a}\,$
- $\;\sum_{y=1}^x \left(\cfrac{2}{3}\right)^y=\cfrac{2}{3}\sum_{y=1}^{x} \left(\cfrac{2}{3}\right)^{y-1}=\cfrac{2}{3}\sum_{y=0}^{x-1} \left(\cfrac{2}{3}\right)^y=\cfrac{2}{3}\left(1 + \cfrac{2}{3}+\cdots+\left(\cfrac{2}{3}\right)^{x-1}\right)\,$
- Use the previous two steps to calculate the sum, replace in the original expression, simplify.